# Adding root to API blueprint when using data structures

Tags: json, apiblueprint

i have been trying for hours in trying to get this to work, been reading up on all the docs.

I need e array to have a root (as per the json specification), while using the data structures i have already defined. What do i need to change to the api blueprint?

JSON NEEDED

```
{ “highlights”:    
  [
    {
     “id”: 1,
    “text”: ”some text”
},
  {
    “id”: 2,
    “text”: ”some text”    
  },    
 ]
}
```

API BLUEPRINT

```
# Data Structures

## Highlight1 (object)

+ id : 1

+ text: "never knew this"

## Highlight2 (object)

+ id : 1

+ text: "never knew this”

# Group

## Feed [/highlights]

### List [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

<!-- this does not generate the root -->     
+ Attributes (array[Highlight1, Highlight2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like the following:

```
+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Attributes
        + highlights (array)
            + (Highlight1)
            + (Highlight2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Ended up doing this: + Attributes
        + highlights (array[Highlight1, Highlight2])